# Form not submitting on clicking submit

Tags: forms, submit

I have a simple form, trying to submit the same, but when I click submit the progress on the button is constant, the form doesn't get submitted. You can take a look at what is happening at www.factore.in/source/forms/contact/index.php

Below is the code of the php page, Please advice:

```
<?php
    require dirname(__FILE__)."/j-pro/php/csrf.php";
    $new_token = new CSRF("contact");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Contact form</title>

    <!-- Your META here -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="j-pro/css/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="j-pro/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="j-pro/css/j-pro-modern.css">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="j-pro/js/jquery.2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="j-pro/js/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="j-pro/js/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="j-pro/js/jquery.j-pro.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="bg-pic">
    <div class="j-wrapper j-wrapper-400">

        <form action="j-pro/php/action.php" method="post" class="j-pro" id="j-pro" novalidate>

            <div class="j-header">
                <p>Contact form</p>
            </div>
            <!-- end /.header-->

            <div class="j-content">

                <!-- start token -->
                <div class="j-token">
                    <?php echo $new_token->get_token();?>
                </div>
                <!-- end token -->

                <!-- start name -->
                <div class="j-unit">
                    <label class="j-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="j-input">
                        <label class="j-icon-right" for="name">
                            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="e.g. John Doe" id="name" name="name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end name -->

                <!-- start email -->
                <div class="j-unit">
                    <label class="j-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="j-input">
                        <label class="j-icon-right" for="email">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        </label>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="email@example.com" id="email" name="email">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end email -->

                <!-- start phone -->
                <div class="j-unit">
                    <label class="j-label">Phone</label>
                    <div class="j-input">
                        <label class="j-icon-right" for="phone">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="telephone or mobile" id="phone" name="phone">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end phone -->

                <!-- start textarea -->
                <div class="j-unit">
                    <label class="j-label">Message</label>
                    <div class="j-input">
                        <textarea placeholder="your message..." spellcheck="false" name="message"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- end textarea -->

                <!-- start response from server -->
                <div class="j-response"></div>
                <!-- end response from server -->

            </div>
            <!-- end /.content -->

            <div class="j-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="j-primary-btn">Send</button>
            </div>
            <!-- end /.footer -->

        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            // Phone masking
            $('#phone').mask('999 999-9999', {placeholder:'x'});

            // Validation
            $( "#j-pro" ).justFormsPro({
                rules: {
                    name: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    },
                    phone: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    message: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    name: {
                        required: "Add your name"
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: "Add your email",
                        email: "Incorrect email format"
                    },
                    phone: {
                        required: "Add your phone"
                    },
                    message: {
                        required: "Enter your message"
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanking you
Regards
cheers
AG

Comment: Hi, Appreciate the prompt response, could you be more specific as to which plugin and how do I go about disabling it?

Answer (score 0):

Running the form you linked did submit as intended, you can see the request made in Chrome Developer Tools.

The reason it is failing is due to an error with your PHP server-side code, this was the response:

```
PHP Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in \\sambaf\sites\factore.in\public_html\source\forms\contact\j-pro\php\action.php on line 71
PHP Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in \\sambaf\sites\factore.in\public_html\source\forms\contact\j-pro\php\action.php on line 71
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in \\sambaf\sites\factore.in\public_html\source\forms\contact\j-pro\php\action.php on line 71
```

Comment: how do I know which file and what is the correction that I need to do?

Comment: The lines I pasted above show you the file path and line number of the faulting code.

Comment: $re_captcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(RECAPTCHA_SERVER_SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());

Comment: That error indicates that your PHP version does not support namespacing (PHP 5.2 and below). You will need to update PHP on the server for that code to work.

Comment: I changed the php version to 7 on the server it was at 5.6, but I'm still getting the same error. Sorry for the trouble, but not good at Js or php.

Comment: any suggestions, is the line of code correct what I sent ? appreciate the help.

Comment: You shouldn't be getting that error if you're running PHP 5.6 or 7.0, I'd suggest you check your server setup to ensure your web server is loading the correct version of PHP.